# How to make SOAP Client for requests/responses in a C program

Tags: c++, c, http, soap

I have a C program that needs to send continuous requests and receive responses from a SOAP Server.

Shall I wrap the C program to in a C++ class and perform C# interface?

Or is there a way to code a C SOAP Client directly?

I have a custom HTTP headers to be included in the request.

Here is an example test from the SOAP Server documentation on how to call it but I can't figure out how to integrate it to my C program:

```
POST /otd HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: OT
Host: localhost:9002
Content-Length: 196
Connection: Close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <doSome/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: So you're asking how to make a GET/POST request in C ? I don't understand the queestion "Or is there a way to code a c SOAP client directly" if the question is implying is there a way to utilise networking and sockets in C then yes you can do that. Why do you need C++ classes or a C# interface?

Comment: SOAP is just XML over HTTP/S. There are plenty of XML libraries and HTTP libraries available for C (for instance, libxml2 and libcurl), you don't need to resort to using C++ or C#.

Comment: @RemyLebeau libxml2 is developed for the Gnome project and I am working on an in production C program, I don't know if it supports it. I don't know about libcurl will check it out thanks!

Comment: @Akali My question was rather about SOAP libraries or a way to dealing with SOAP communications in C

Comment: @yassine libxml2 is an open source library. It works with multiple compilers, and it works outside of the Gnome system just fine.